# How to save tensors from “MATLAB Tensor Toolbox Version 2.5” into text file?

Tags: matlab

Does anyone here use "MATLAB Tensor Toolbox Version 2.5 (Sandia National Laboratories)" with Matlab to operate tensors? **I would like to know how to save the tensor/sptensor from it into a text file.**

I found a function "export_data()" but it supports "tensor" type and doesn't work on "sptensor". I think it would be perfect **if there is a way to write a "sptensor" into text files** with the format like it shows via "disp(sptensor)" function. e.g.

(57,211,138) 0.0000

(57,211,141) 1.1063

(57,211,142) 1.1063

(57,211,143) 0.0000

(57,211,144) 0.6213

I think either I can save the whole sptensor in one time, or we can iterate it and save elements one by one. Do you have any idea to achieve this? How you store the (reconstructed) tensor data for further process?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this toolbox, but you can write it manually using the following snipet of code in a loop:

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt','a');
for n = 1:4
    x = randn(4,1);
    fprintf(fid,'(%f,%f,%f)%f',x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4));
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Note that you should also write a line that provides the size of the sparse tensor (you can't reliably guess the size of the tensor from the coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `export_data(tensor,"filename.txt")`. The export_data function exports the tensor data in simple ASCII text format. The tensor can be any tensor like sptensor, ktensor, ttensor etc.